# Can't find out how to pass chosen element from the form to the view. Email gets sent to wrong address

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

in my project i need to build a function that send email to the trip owner depending on the button clicked accept or refuse:
here is my views code :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Guide,Trip 
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from django.conf import settings 
def accept(request):
    trips = Trip.objects.all()
    z = {'aw': trips}

    if request.method == 'POST':


        for i, trip in enumerate(trips):

            trip_id = request.POST.get('trip_id_{}'.format(i)) 
            #send email to the trip_id owner 
            print("trip_id =", trip_id)
           

            if 'accept_{}'.format(i+1) in request.POST:
                email_msg = EmailMessage(
                    'Trip accepted',
                    'Hi there! Your trip has been accepted.',
                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                    [trip.owner_email],
                )
                email_msg.fail_silently = True
                email_msg.send() 
            elif 'refuse_{}'.format(i+1) in request.POST:
                email_msg = EmailMessage(
                    'Trip refused',
                    'Hi there! Your trip has been refused.',
                    settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                    [trip.owner_email],
                )
                email_msg.fail_silently = True
                email_msg.send()

            


    return render(request, 'system/accept.html', z)
```

here is my template code :

```
{% block content %}

{% for x in aw %}
    {{x.owner}}
    {{x.owner_email}}
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'accept' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="trip_id_{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ x.id }}">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="accept_{{ forloop.counter }}" value="accept">
        <input type="submit" name="refuse_{{ forloop.counter }}" value="refuse">
    </form>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

my web page looks like this
[image]
but when i press accept button to send accept email to the second email the first email receives the acceptance email .

i tried printing the `trip_id` values to see if they are correct , but i dont understand the `trip_id=NONE` [image]

Comment: The second screenshot contains valuable debugging details, please post this log as text instead of image.

Answer (score 0):

*too long for comment*

This query `Trip.objects.all()` does not define row order explicitly thus `Trip` order in the list is not [guaranteed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (DBMS does not matter). When you handle `GET` - rows are returned in one order (it may be different each time), when you handle `POST` - rows may be returned in the same or *whatever else* order. This means that when you iterate through the rowset same record gets different index each time.

`for i, trip in enumerate(trips)` - this looks like a shot in the foot on a peaceful Sunday morning.

Your form and the view cannot handle multiple choices, view will be executed for a single chosen `trip_id`. Enumerating through all the `Trip.objects.all()` (which may contain *any number* of records thus running trough the rowset may take unpredictably long time) is an overkill and a long tough way to do something small and easy.

Just pass directly chosen `trip_id` itself from the form.

And even better: split the view into two

- GET-only view which shows the list and has no additional args
- PUT-only view which sends email and requires `trip_id` argument (yes, with a separate url pattern)

The sending view will now need to get only single record by `.get(pk=trip_id)`. No need in looping over all the records to find particular one - DB can do this very well. All the *look around* code can be removed.

Also in respect to DRY it would be better to get rid of copy-pasted `EmailMessage` instantiation code and leave inside if-else only mail subject and body "computations".